# AdBlock Plus blocking SO ads and bad practice from SO on showing same ad multiple times on same page

Tags: discussion, advertising

Wow. By accident I was using Google Chrome and noticed suddenly all the ads in SO! I use Firefox with AdBlock Plus installed and I have never seen an ad ever since I started using SO. I never told ABP to blocks ads from SO. So it seems they are blocking it through their subscription filter server.

Jeff Atwood has been talking about ads on the site and I was wondering what he was talking about because I never saw the ads and it never occurred to me ABP was blocking them. Now the ads look annoying to me. I know a free site has to make some money but I NEVER click on an ad.

I am sorry but I have to block the ads. I find them annoying and why do I have to see the same ad on the same page more than once. That TFS report ad is there TWICE. I can see it now twice above the fold! This seems like forcing ads on me.

Comment: ... is this a question?

Comment: -1 for pointless rant.

Comment: @Farseeker, on meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/33705/… Jeff suggests that MSO is more of a discussion site, where 'not a real question' is NOT a valid reason to close because posts aren't necessarily questions. – pavium 18 mins ago

Comment: No it's not a question. That's why there's a tag called 'discussion'.

Comment: @JonB: You must like big intrusive ads.

Comment: "I NEVER click on an ad" -- well gee, if you *block* them all the time, I guess you wouldn't click on them, would you?

Comment: @'smart'Alex: . I don't click on ads when they appear.. on any site. well.. maybe one in a half a million.

Comment: Nice flashing black attention grabber!

Comment: @Farseeker Not every post has to be a question on meta. For example a suggestion is not a question. and yes there's an implied question. why the same ad above the fold twice?

Comment: [Here's a better version of this post.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281965/whats-up-with-this-post-and-what-appears-to-be-double-careers-ads-in-the-same-p/281966#281966)

Comment: OP, get [AdBlock Plus for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb). Problem fixed.

Comment: Someone needs to calibrate his intrusion detector.

Comment: @haykam I guess the presentation is very important here since the other post and mine are basically talking about the same thing. Yet his was upvoted 13 times and mine was downvoted 14 times.

Answer (score 18):

I agree. Stack Overflow is the worst. Just so you all know what he's talking about, this is **exactly** what it looks like if you disable adblock on StackOverflow.com...

[image]

We used to do that whole [Responsible Advertising](http://inedomedia.com/Responsible-Advertising.aspx) thing.... but screw it, *we're rich, b#tches*!.

Comment: Would it be enable and not disable?

Comment: "I like money."

Comment: I visit thousands of sites with ads. %99 of the ads are either in the side bars or header. SO had a full width ad TWICE in the same viewable page (I didn't have to scroll). Didn't I hear Jeff complain of practices like this but he doesn't it himself? WTF

Comment: @Tony: Talk is cheap. You can say what you want in theory, but in practice it rarely ever works. They have to support the sites somehow.

Comment: Fortunately my sarcasm detector rebooted before I could downvote this for being untrue.

Answer (score 16):

You mean those small 220x250, non-animated, non-flashy static content ads bother you? I specifically *white-listed* the SO family sites because they're some of my favorite ads online - completely non intrusive. Not a single one has ever tried to cover up my content with some annoying fake window or a car driving across the screen (I'm looking at you, imdb!)

Also, for what it's worth - [THERE IS NO PAGE FOLD](http://www.thereisnopagefold.com/).

Comment: Wonder why that site (http://www.ThereIsNoPageFold.com/) needs jQuery.

Comment: @random: shutup, random. Everything is better with jQuery.

Comment: @Shog9 Hand that memo to Google Wave.

Comment: The ads between the answers are intrusive. The page fold is where it shows the question and where you don't have to scroll down once you figure the question is not that interesting.

Comment: These are the 730 x 90 ads. What I am seeing now. The ads that take the full width of the answer column.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich: Just log in. With 1,396 rep, you should only see the sidebar ads.

Comment: @Jared what do you call the browser view prt before scrolling.. if it's not the page fold?

Comment: @Jared you call those content column full width ads between the answers non intrusive? Your definition of non intrusive is different than most people. it doesn't have to be animated to be intrusive.

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying that you would rather pay a subscription fee than let others see the ads and potentially click on them, while you continue to block them?

The money for all those servers and all that software has to come from someplace....

Comment: I would pay $5/month than be bombarded with ads. I just hate ads that are interspersed between the text I read. I find them too invasive. I feel the SO folks are forcing them on me as if the right column is not enough. The probably figured that people ignore these. Yeah I understand the ad revenue model. I did mention that in my post.