# Let AdBlock Plus unblock SE ads

Tags: feature-request, advertising

I recently added "Ad-block Plus" to my Safari configuration and noticed that all the ads on SE disappeared.  Now "Ad-block Plus" maintains a list of sites that comply with their idea of "non-obtrusive."  I've **never** considered SE ads obtrusive,¹ so I would suggest contacting them to get added to their "non-intrusive" list.

¹*Unike* whoever wrote [AdBlock Plus blocking SO ads and bad practice from SO on showing same ad multiple times on same page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33702/adblock-plus-blocking-so-ads-and-bad-practice-from-so-on-showing-same-ad-multipl)

Comment: So whitelist SE sites... you can manually turn off Adblock on any site you wish.

Comment: We've been [pretty transparent in the past](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/02/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/) regarding our opinion of ad blockers. Short answer: We don't care if you block ads.

Comment: @Catija: It doesn't matter to me personally whether they are blocked or not, since they are so unobtrusive I don't notice them.  I DID notice ABP proudly informing me it had blocked them!

Comment: i rather suggest to use [uBlockO](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/) anyway! it has useful additional functions, is [lighter on resources](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/#performance) and also easier to tune and use. -- regarding main topic: eyeo GmbH (company of ABP) seems to be a kind of a modern highwayman... i don't want a company to decide what i should see or not, and even less to make a business out of this. and with a big number of users it becomes a kind of a gatekeeper, which currently reminds me of levering out the [net neutrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_neutrality).

Comment: *to make it short and applicable:* use [**uBlockO**](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/), if the preset/available filters aren't enough, with [**FilterLists.com**](https://filterlists.com/) there is a really nice independent project for collecting & rating filter-lists; and white-list sites YOU want to support with [one simple click](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/How-to-whitelist-a-web-site) yourself.

Comment: I will definitely put uBlock on my Tor and FireFox.  Unfortunately, I mostly use Safari.

Comment: @WGroleau: well... i never use safari; but there is a beta of a port, maybe worth to try: https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/#safari-macos

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I've never considered SE ads obtrusive,¹ so I would suggest contacting them to get added to their "non-intrusive" list.

And how do you think ABP earns money? By letting companies pay to get on the list*. No way SE will pay for that.

<sup>*</sup> [Source](http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-does-adblock-plus-make-money/):

> Adblock Plus generates revenue mainly through the Acceptable Ads program. According to the company, some users do donate, but the bulk of cash comes from the whitelisted ads licensing model. If a company gains over 10 million ad impressions a month extra due to the Acceptable Ads program, they must contribute towards Adblock Plus' upkeep.

Given that number of 10 million ad impressions: That's two or three per page, so after 3.3-5 mln page views a month SO Inc. has to pay. Stack Overflow only has over 24 milllion page views *per day*...

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it costs.  But it only costs if you're over ten million a month.  SE is big, but that big?  Can individual sites be counted separately?

Comment: 10 mln ad impressions. That is two or three per page, so after 4-5 mln page views a month SE has to pay. Stack Overflow only has over 24 mln page views PER DAY...